# Notation for element in set builder notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

If I want to describe some elements of a real space (say $\mathbb{R}^3$) is it proper to write:

$$\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid P(x) \}$$

or better

$$\{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid P(\mathbf{x}) \}$$

where with bold we denote an ordered tuple?

Comment: Typo in the second one? You want $P(\mathbf{x})$.

Comment: Whatever you do, make sure you stick to your choices consistently.

Comment: By writing “$x\in\Bbb R^3$”, you identify $x$ as a vector. From there on, in my opinion, typography is immaterial, as long as it’s consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen both bold and "non-bolded" font used to denote elements in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. However, it is highly dependent on the context of the subject matter you are working in.

For example, in more engineering mathematics or physics books authors will bold face elements **x $\in \mathbb{R}^{3}$** to emphasize them as *vectors* (here is a good demonstration of [this](https://iupac.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/ICTNS-On-the-use-of-italic-and-roman-fonts-for-symbols-in-scientific-text.pdf)).

In other literature such as in [*Partial Differential Equations* by Lawrence C. Evens](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/%7Exushijie/pdf/textbooks/pde-evans.pdf), we can see that the author on page $2$ makes quick work in writing $x \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$; as we can see, not in bold face font. With that said, I would say both $$\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{3}: P(x)\}$$ and $$\{\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}: P(\textbf{x})\}$$ are proper and are widely used in different settings.